# Fetch a department's total, Its percentage of earnings for that site and its percentage of earnings across the company

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use the data from one table to produce the result set 
| Dept | TotalValue | PercentageOfSite | PercentageOfCompany |

Any improvements or advice on the below would be helpful.

```
DECLARE @SiteNo INT = 1
DECLARE @SessionDateFrom DATETIME = '2017/02/01'
DECLARE @SessionDateTo DATETIME = '2017/03/01'

    CREATE TABLE #DepartmentSales
(
    DeptName VARCHAR(50), 
    DeptNo SMALLINT,
    Value MONEY,
    SiteNo SMALLINT
)

INSERT INTO #DepartmentSales
SELECT DeptName
    ,DeptNo
    ,SUM(Value) AS SalesValue
    ,SiteNo
FROM PLUSalesDetailExtended
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @SessionDateFrom AND @SessionDateTo
AND TermNo = 0
GROUP BY DeptName, DeptNo, SiteNo

SELECT DeptName
    ,DeptNo
    ,Value AS SalesValue
    ,Value / (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM #DepartmentSales WHERE SiteNo = @SiteNo) AS SitePercent
    ,Value / (SELECT SUM(Value) FROM #DepartmentSales) AS CompanyPercent

FROM #DepartmentSales
WHERE SiteNo = @SiteNo
GROUP BY DeptName
    ,DeptNo
    ,Value

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DepartmentSales') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #DepartmentSales
End
```

Any further questions please ask and I shall try to answer them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the same GROUP BY in the 2nd Select is unneccessary, the data is already unique.

I prefer writing this kind of logic (where you need multiple aggregation levels) as a single Select using Analytical Functions, i.e. Group Sums:

```
WITH AllSites AS
 (  -- calculate the percentages for all sites
    SELECT DeptName 
        ,DeptNo
        ,SUM(Value) AS SalesValue
        ,SiteNo
    -- Analytical Functions are calculated after GROUP BY/HAVING,
    -- thus you can nest the aggregated Sum in the Group Sum  
        ,SUM(Value) / SUM(SUM(Value)) OVER (PARTITION BY SiteNo) AS SitePercent
        ,SUM(Value) / SUM(SUM(Value)) OVER () AS CompanyPercent
    FROM PLUSalesDetailExtended
    WHERE DATE BETWEEN @SessionDateFrom AND @SessionDateTo
    AND TermNo = 0

    GROUP BY DeptName, DeptNo, SiteNo
 )
-- return only one site
SELECT * FROM AllSites
WHERE SiteNo = @SiteNo
```

If this is more or less efficient than your current approach depends mainly on he number of sites, at least it's simpler (for me) and easy to extend to multiple/all sites.